# When I use string,find[::] in another def, the string.find() says it's attribution doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x

When i use `find()` like `string.find[::]` in another `def` function, it says that says attribution error. Why does it not work?

```
def parts(phrase):
    space=phrase.find(' ')
    first_word=phrase[0:space]
    return first_word

def rest_of_phrase(phrase):
    space=phrase.find(' ')
    rest_of_phrase=phrase[space+1:]
    return rest_of_phrase

def jesus_this_part_is_hard(first_word,rest_of_phrase):
    total_num=len(rest_of_phrase)
    count=0
    savepoint=[]
    while total_num<count:
        for i in total_num:
            if i==' ':
                savepoint+=[i]
            count+=1
    print(first_word," ")
    x=savepoint[::-1]
    for i in x:
        if i==x[0]:
            print(rest_of_phrase[i:]," ")
            p=i
        elif i!=x[0]:
            print(rest_of_phrase[i:p],"")
            p=i


def main():
    phrase = input("Enter the phrase")
    parts(phrase)
    parts(rest_of_phrase)
    jesus_this_part_is_hard(first_word,rest_of_phrase)
```

The result that I got was line 2, in parts
    space=phrase.find(' ')

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: Please copy/paste code to the question. We can't copy/paste a screenshot to our own systems to test.

Comment: And please add the exact error message

Comment: Sorry new at this.

Comment: Err... you do realise you can do, `first_word, _, rest_of_phrase = phrase.partition(' ')` right?

Comment: Right, but it still get the error AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'find'

Answer (score 1):

`parts(rest_of_phrase)` here `rest_of_phrase` is function hence you are seeing this error
replace your main function with below and it will fix syntax errors (Not sure about the logical errors)

```
def main()
  phrase = input("Enter the phrase")
  first_word = parts(phrase)
  rest_of_phrase = rest_of_phrase(phrase)
  jesus_this_part_is_hard(first_word,rest_of_phrase)
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason it works, still not sure the logic behind it.

Comment: This is the answer. I'd note that it's usually a bad idea to use the same name for multiple different things. In this code `rest_of_phrase` is both the name of a function, and a variable containing the return value of that function. It would be better (less likely to cause confusing bugs) to use separate names. Try `rest = rest_of_phrase(phrase)` and pass `rest` as the argument to the last function.